# Apache 2.4 alias directory prevent users to open documents changing url

Tags: php, apache, alias

I have an Apache 2.4 server running, in which I have configured an alias, which redirects to another folder on another disk on the server where I have files (pdfs, images, etc.).
The problem is that when the user opens a file, the url is seen in the browser's address bar. And the user by simply changing the file name, can find files that they don't have to see.

Here's my setting in httpd.conf:

```
<IfModule alias_module>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "c:/Apache24/cgi-bin/"
    
    Alias /archivosHCL "C:/ARCHIVOS/HCL"
    <Directory "C:/ARCHIVOS/HCL">
      Options FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
        
</IfModule>
```

Is there a way for the user to only access those files if they click on a link, but not by manually inserting a URL?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way for Apache to know if someone clicked a link or if they typed in a URL - those incoming requests both look the same to Apache.  Either move things out of that folder that you don't want to share, or implement some server-side code (for example, in PHP) that can act as an intermediary and manage authorisation